# How to map SQL to Liquibase XML Tag

Tags: mysql, xml, database, liquibase

I have following SQL

```
 INSERT INTO a_c (a_id, c_id)
   SELECT DISTINCT
       ab.a_id,
       bc.c_id
   FROM a_b ab
       INNER JOIN b_c bc
           ON ab.b_id = bc.b_id;
```

How can I replace this SQL block with Liqubase XML Tag

We could do like this but. I wanted to know if we can totally use XML Tag

```
<sql>
            <![CDATA[
                 INSERT INTO a_c (a_id, c_id)
                     SELECT DISTINCT
                        ab.a_id,
                        bc.c_id
                    FROM a_b ab
                        INNER JOIN b_c bc
                            ON ab.b_id = bc.b_id;
            ]]>
</sql>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because there are no characters in your SQL that are illegal in XML, you can completely remove the CDATA begin/end tags, and this should work without any issues.